# addEventListener after change event

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with one dropdown list and one table. The users choose from the dropdown and dynamically I populate the table from my db. 
Example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <label asp-for="CCDescr" class="control-label">Cost Center</label>
  <select asp-for="CCCode" class="form-control"
    asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.CostCenterList, "CCCode", "CCDescr"))"></select>
</div>
<div class="tg-wrap" id="table" hidden>
  <table class="tg">
    <tr>..Headers..</tr>
    <tr>..Data..</tr>
    <tr>..Data..</tr>
    <tr>..Data..</tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have written a js script to read my data from the db using the controller. And then I populate my table like

```
$("#table").empty();
  items +=
    "<table class='tg'>" +
    "<tr>....</tr>" +
    "</table>"
    $("#table").html(items);
    $("#table").show();
```

I have found a js to short my table and it work for the fist time I load the page, but after the user change the dropdown list and my js run the sort isn't working any more.
The sort function adds a `n.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { for (var t = n.getElementsByClassName("tg"), e = 0; e < r(t); ++e)try { v(t[e]) } catch (n) { } })
 }(document)` but I can't make it work after my dropdownlist and table changes. 
Thanks in advance for your help. 
Regards.
---
For reference I post the hole js for sorting the table (as I said already not my code, something I found online):

```
    <script charset="utf-8">
        var TGSort = window.TGSort || function (n) {
            "use strict";
            function r(n) { return n ? n.length : 0 }
            function t(n, t, e, o = 0) { for (e = r(n); o < e; ++o)t(n[o], o) }
            function e(n) { return n.split("").reverse().join("") }
            function o(n) {
                var e = n[0]; return t(n, function (n) {
                    for (; !n.startsWith(e);)e = e.substring(0, r(e) - 1)
                }), r(e)
            } function u(n, r, e = []) {
                return t(n, function (n) { r(n) && e.push(n) }), e
            } var a = parseFloat; function i(n, r) {
                return function (t) {
                    var e = ""; return t.replace(n, function (n, t, o) { return e = t.replace(r, "") + "." + (o || "").substring(1) }), a(e)
                }
            } var s = i(/^(?:\s*)([+-]?(?:\d+)(?:,\d{3})*)(\.\d*)?$/g, /,/g), c = i(/^(?:\s*)([+-]?(?:\d+)(?:\.\d{3})*)(,\d*)?$/g, /\./g);
            function f(n) { var t = a(n); return !isNaN(t) && r("" + t) + 1 >= r(n) ? t : NaN }
            function d(n) {
                var e = [], o = n; return t([f, s, c], function (u) { var a = [], i = []; t(n, function (n, r) { r = u(n), a.push(r), r || i.push(n) }), r(i) < r(o) && (o = i, e = a) }), r(u(o, function (n) { return n == o[0] })) == r(o) ? e : []
            } function v(n) {
                if ("TABLE" == n.nodeName) {
                    for (var a = function (r) {
                        var e, o, u = [], a = []; return function n(r, e) {
                            e(r), t(r.childNodes, function (r) { n(r, e) })
                        }(n, function (n) { "TR" == (o = n.nodeName) ? (e = [], u.push(e), a.push(n)) : "TD" != o && "TH" != o || e.push(n) }), [u, a]
                    }(), i = a[0], s = a[1], c = r(i), f = c > 1 && r(i[0]) < r(i[1]) ? 1 : 0, v = f + 1, p = i[f], h = r(p), l = [], g = [], N = [], m = v; m < c; ++m) {
                        for (var T = 0; T < h; ++T) {
                            r(g) < h && g.push([]); var C = i[m][T], L = C.textContent || C.innerText || ""; g[T].push(L.trim())
                        } N.push(m - v)
                    } t(p, function (n, t) {
                        l[t] = 0; var a = n.classList; a.add("tg-sort-header"), n.addEventListener("click", function () {
                            var n = l[t]; !function () {
                                for (var n = 0; n < h; ++n) {
                                    var r = p[n].classList; r.remove("tg-sort-asc"), r.remove("tg-sort-desc"), l[n] = 0
                                }
                            }(), (n = 1 == n ? -1 : +!n) && a.add(n > 0 ? "tg-sort-asc" : "tg-sort-desc"), l[t] = n; var i, f = g[t], m = function (r, t) {
                                return n * f[r].localeCompare(f[t]) || n * (r - t)
                            }, T = function (n) {
                                var t = d(n); if (!r(t)) {
                                    var u = o(n), a = o(n.map(e)); t = d(n.map(function (n) { return n.substring(u, r(n) - a) }))
                                } return t
                            }(f); (r(T) || r(T = r(u(i = f.map(Date.parse), isNaN)) ? [] : i)) && (m = function (r, t) {
                                var e = T[r], o = T[t], u = isNaN(e), a = isNaN(o); return u && a ? 0 : u ? -n : a ? n : e > o ? n : e < o ? -n : n * (r - t)
                            }); var C, L = N.slice(); L.sort(m); for (var E = v; E < c; ++E)(C = s[E].parentNode).removeChild(s[E]); for (E = v; E < c; ++E)C.appendChild(s[v + L[E - v]])
                        })
                    })
                }
            } n.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { for (var t = n.getElementsByClassName("tg"), e = 0; e < r(t); ++e)try { v(t[e]) } catch (n) { } })
        }(document)
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Set a id to the select tag

```
<label asp-for="CCDescr" class="control-label">Cost Center</label>
<select id="cost" asp-for="CCCode" class="form-control">
    <option value="test">Test</option>
</select>
```

2) Create a new function in TGSort:

```
  function sort() {
    for (var t = n.getElementsByClassName("tg"), e = 0; e < r(t); ++e) try {
      v(t[e])
    } catch (n) {}
  }
```

3) Replace   n.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",.... ) with:

```
  n.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",sort )
  document.getElementById("cost").addEventListener('change', sort);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I try the above but it didn't work. Still I can sort the table the first time the page loaded but not after the table changes.At the debugger I get an error for  .addEventListener('change', sort); - Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. Action flow is: Load page -run TGSort js ->change ddl -> update table.

Comment: document.getElementById("cost") returns null

Comment: Inspect element in chrome/firefox and see what the id checkbox has. Possible asp.net sets id

Comment: Alternatively I would look at this: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-add-rows.html

Comment: I fix the null property was an mistyping, sorry for that. But still no sort after the table is populated. Maybe because in my js when the ddl changes I recreate the table. Is there a way to trigger the TGSort after the change?